# How to refresh recyclerview adapter when data changes in other fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

**First fragment**

```
private void initRecyclerView() {
        Main.musicList = Main.songs.songs;
        if ((Main.musicList != null) && (!Main.musicList.isEmpty())) {
            // Connects the song list to an adapter
            // (Creates several Layouts from the song list)
            allSongsAdapter = new AllSongsAdapter(getActivity(), Main.musicList);

            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

            recyclerViewSongs.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            recyclerViewSongs.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerViewSongs.setAdapter(allSongsAdapter);
   } 
}
```

In the first fragment i have a recyclerview which displays a list with all songs found on the device and i have an option to delete a song which changes the data in my arraylist **Main.musicList** by rescanning all songs on the device.

So all my other arraylists in my app still have a reference to that deleted song.

So how can i call notifySetDataChanged on all recyclerview adapters in other fragments when i delete an item in the first fragment?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use ViewModel in your Activity which holds these fragments.
2. Wrap your song list in LiveData object. This can be observed by all
   of your fragments depending on their lifecycle (when the fragment is
   in OnResumed state, it will be automatically notified when your list
   has changed)
3. In related fragment start to observe LiveData and on
   change update your adapter.

Related topics:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54
Hope I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way will be to use `BroadcastReceiver`. try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875292/5729007) answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use EventBus to trigger the method, by which reyclcer view adapter will be notified